# How to count total record apply with WHERE clause when using pagination in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have some problem to count total record using WHERE clause condition with pagination in Laravel.

Ex: I have total 100 records (female students = 40 and male student = 60) and display 10 records per page.

So I want to count total records of female student when display in homepage.

I have tried like this `{{$StudentInfo->where("sex",1)->count()}}` but it count record only in current page not all record and when I used `total()` it does not work `{{$StudentInfo->where("sex",1)->total()}}.`

Note: `sex = 1 (female), sex = 0 (male).`
Thanks.

Comment: you need to pass `total_count` from separate variable...

Comment: So I need to write another query to count it?

Comment: can you update your query...

Comment: I can't update my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{$StudentInfo->where("sex",1)->get()->count()}}
```

Hope this works..

Comment: It show error Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in...

Answer (score 0):

Do `$StudentInfo->total();`

Check the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination

Comment: yes but I want to get total only female student. How to do this? -Luis Fernando Montoya

Comment: then, you need a separate query for that, you cannot reuse the one with the pagination.